# Комментарий или ответ?

Tags: обсуждение

Очень часто попадаются простые вопросы, которые уже много раз обсуждались много где и ответ заключается в паре слов. Стоит ли писать полноценный ответ на них или достаточно оставить комментарий?

Данная тема возникла после этого [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656239/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-span-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0?noredirect=1#comment942105_656239)

Свою позицию я изложил там же но продублирую:

"Я не пишу это как ответ, потому, что не считаю, что данный вопрос будет полезен для сообщества т.к. это базовый html/css. Ответа заслуживают вопросы, которые решают частые проблемы многих программистов. В данном случае нужна просто подсказка по азам одному человеку."

Уже видел на мете тему с таким же названием но исчерпывающего ответа не нашел

Comment: Ответ должен быть ответом. Комментарии в любой момент должно быть можно удалить. То, что вопрос простой, не значит, что он менее ценный.

Comment: @vp_arth он менее ценный, потому, что почти все знают на него ответ. И стоит ли захламлять ресурс ответами, которые можно найти за минуту в гугле?

Comment: Вы не правы, ваша оценка весьма субъективна. Из множества незнающих даже нашёлся человек, который разместил вопрос. Найдутся и другие. Если за минуту в гугле мы находим не ruSO - стоит.

Comment: @vp_arth При ответе на большинство вопросов я гуглю ответ, разбив вопрос на части и почти всегда на первых строчках ruSO)

Comment: Спасибо тем, кто не считал эти вопросы-ответы хламом ;)

Comment: Когда вы знаете, что ответ на вопрос уже у нас есть - существует опция "закрыть вопрос, как дубликат"

Comment: @vp_arth Это относилось к вопросам, где человек спрашивает "Мне надо сделать вот это, это и это" и не догадывается прогуглить 3 разных "это" отдельно. Я не считаю эти вопросы хламом. Они кому-то помогают. Но мало кому

Answer (score 2):

Любой вопрос, заданный на этом сайте, заслуживает либо закрытия с последующим удалением, либо ответа.

Если вопрос удалят - то дилемма "ответ или комментарий" не имеет смысла.

Если вопрос закрыт но не удален - то он либо дубликат (и тогда имеет ответ на другой странице), либо будет удален позже.

Если вопрос не закрыт - на него нужен ответ.

---

Таким образом, ответ никогда не помешает, за исключением ситуации когда вы намеренно не хотите его давать чтобы не поощрять автора вопроса. Но в таком случае и комментарий тоже будет лишним.

Comment: Обращаю внимание читателей: **в ответе ни слова о голосах**. И 
это неспроста. Бывают интересные и хорошие вопросы, которые, к сожалению, требуют закрытия. Как и бывают безнадёжно плохие вопросы, находящиеся тем не менее в области сайта.